# examples of The precedence of && is higher than that of ||

Tags: c, logical-operators, operator-precedence

The K&R c says: The precedence of && is higher than that of ||

but why The following code, the `c` and `d` is still -1:

```
int a, b = -1, c = -1, d = -1;
a = (b = 1) || (0, c = 0) && (1, d = 0);
```

Comment: Because the right hand side of `||` is [short-circuited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and never evaluated.

Comment: @dxiv, I use = to watch what part is evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Because `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, your statement parses like this:

```
a = ((b = 1) || ((0, c = 0) && (1, d = 0)));
```

So you have `(b = 1)` as the left operand to `||` and `(0, c = 0) && (1, d = 0)` as the right operand.  The left operand is evaluated first, so you have 1 on the left side.  Because of that, the value of the entire `||` expression is known so the right side, i.e. `(0, c = 0) && (1, d = 0)`, is not evaluated.

So `c` and `d` are not updated.

Comment: And once again, return to the old saw that precedence is about grouping, not order of evaluation.

Comment: @dbush because logical expressions are evaluated from left to right I can't imagine any expression where this precedence makes any difference.

Comment: @0___________， for exp `1 || 0 && 0`，if `&&` is higher，then equals to `1 || ( 0 && 0)`，then the value of exp is `1`，if `||` is higher，then equals to `(1 || 0) && 0`，the value is of exp is `0`，so has difference.